# Counting characters using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeydown, onkeyup

I have the following code:

**PHP**

```
<input style="color:red;font-size:12pt;font-style:italic;" 
    readonly="" type="text" name="q22length" size="3" maxlength="3" value="50"/>
<textarea 
    onkeydown="textCounter(document.frmSurvey.q22,document.frmSurvey.q22length,50);mand();" 
    onkeyup="textCounter(document.frmSurvey.q22,document.frmSurvey.q22length,50)" 
    class="scanwid" name="q22" id="q22" rows="5" cols="">
</textarea>
```

**Jscript**

```
function textCounter(field,cntfield,maxlimit) {
    if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
    field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
    else
    cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lh2UU/

The code should count the number down in the Input tab and then stop the user from adding further characters beyond the limit set.  However, it's not working and I can't see why - any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1: jQuery

Seeing as you have jQuery tagged, I'm going to give you a jQuery solution:

```
$(function() {
    // Define our maximum length
    var maxLength = 50;

    // Our input event handler, which fires when the input changes
    $('textarea.scanwid').on('input', function() {
        // Pull the input text and its length
        var value = this.value,
            length = value.length;

        // Check if the length is greater than the maximum
        if (length > maxLength) {
            // If it is, strip everything after the maximum amount
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, maxLength);

            // Ensure our counter value displays 0 rather than -1
            length = maxLength;
        }

        // Update our counter value
        $('input[name="q22length"]').val(maxLength - length);
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Lh2UU/8/).

---

### Method 2: HTML and jQuery

It's also worth noting that we could just stick the `maxlength` attribute onto our `textarea` element:

```
<textarea ... maxlength="50"></textarea>
```

We can then update our counter using this:

```
$(function() {
    var maxLength = +$('textarea.scanwid').attr('maxlength');

    $('textarea.scanwid').on('input', function() {
        $('input[name="q22length"]').val(maxLength - this.value.length);
    });
});
```

[**Second JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Lh2UU/9/).

Comment: Thanks James - much appreciated, far more elegant than the existing solution.